# Chrome not working on a remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, remote-desktop

Chrome works fine when I'm physically using my computer, but when I connect to it through RDP (Remote Desktop) it doesn't load pages. Both IE and Firefox work fine in all situations.

Is it a known bug bug in Chrome or what? I din't find any information in Google. Note that this has nothing to do with the "Chrome Remote Desktop" extension.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a guess, but maybe it has to do with GPU acceleration not working over RDP. Can you try adding the `--disable-gpu` flag after `chrome.exe` in the shortcut?

Or maybe turning off GPU related items in `chrome://flags/`?

Answer (score 2):

*Thanks for the correct answer, Louis, here are some more hints:*

Starting Chrome with the `--disable-gpu` option works for me. To do so, create a **shortcut** with the following target:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-gpu
```

Turning off the use of graphic acceleration in chrome://flags didn't work for me.

Also, make sure that you **untick "Let Google Chrome run in the background"** in the taskbar. Otherwise the --disable-gpu option is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved on my end simply by disabling the "Continue running apps in the background after closing Google Chrome" option.

It's in the advanced settings and "system" section of google chrome, no need to add --disable-gpu in the target for me

Thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

Changing performance setting under system properties to adjust best performance helped me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at your proxy settings in the working IE browser and make sure that these match the same in the Chrome, I had this issue when using SSH.

Comment: I´m not using a proxy.